# Mosaic Jquery Plugin Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, jquery-plugins

I am using a CMS for a website and I have to change how some images are placed on the page to avoid paying the highest subscription fee for my client.

The template uses the Mosaic Jquery Plugin (http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/), which displays mouse-hover overlays on images and turns them into a light box.

Orginally, Each image was generated on the page with in such a manner:

```
    <div class="mosaic-block fourth fade">
    <a href="{tag_Home Page Featured Large_value}" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="{tag_Home Page Featured Caption}"></a>
    <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="{tag_Home Page Featured Thumb_value}" alt="{tag_name_nolink}" /></div>
</div>
```

Rendered:

```
<div class="mosaic-block fourth fade">
<a href="/img/mock2.jpg" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Insert Your Title" style="display: inline; opacity: 0;"></a>
<div class="mosaic-backdrop" style="display: block;"><img src="/img/mock2.jpg" alt="Project Name"></div>
```

This worked fine as each image rendered on the page with the mosaic divs, then the mosaic jquery code would recognise this, create thumbnails, overlays and a lightbox feature.

However, I am now generating the images from a gallery feature (without the {tags}). To do this I am using a XML file generated rom the gallery feature.

```
<gallery>
```

I then use jquery/ajax to append each item into the correct mosaic divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:'/gallery/footer/PhotoGallery.xml',  // Add your url to your photo gallery xml feed
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: xmlParser
    });

    // don't touch anything under me
    function xmlParser(xml) {
        $(xml).find("img").each(function () {                       
        $(".footer-images").append('<div class="mosaic-block half fade"><a href="/gallery/footer/' + $(this).attr('src') + '" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '"></a><div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="/gallery/footer/' + $(this).attr('src') + '" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '" /></div></div></div>');
        });
    // don't touch anything above me
    }
});
```

On the html page each image renders as:

```
<div class="mosaic-block half fade"><a href="/gallery/footer/Lounge.JPG" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Lounge"></a><div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="/gallery/footer/Lounge.JPG" alt="The Lounge"></div></div>
```

This matches the layout of the original render above. However, the Mosaic Jquery is not applying the different display styles and opacity (which changes on hover).

I have tried changing position of javascript for the append jquery to be before the mosaic, which doesn't work. also, the divs around all of the images doesn't effect the plugin either because I copy and pasted the appended XML straight into the html and the jquery was applied correctly. This led me to try playing with document.ready and window.onload = etc. but I had no success..

One thing to note: When I open the light box from an image that has loaded correctly I can see all of the images in the light box gallery even though the other ones aren't displaying on the page correctly. I think the template is also using a fancybox jquery plugin: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: you have to instantiate your plugin inside your callback, but better even, just pay the license or a proper developer

Comment: The Jquery plugin is free and I shouldn't need to pay a proper developer considering the code is working! It seems to be a loading issue. How would the instantiate work?

Comment: it instantiates the plugin

Comment: yeah so you mean it is loading immediately? However, I have placed the appending jquery before the mosaic jquery and considering scripts load in order there shouldn't be a problem.